# I still don't understand why is it so hard to copy a simple small prefab from one project to another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I just copy the prefab file from folder to folder it won't work.
I will not see the prefab with all the materials textures.

In my original project after made changed to the GameObject in this case a door I dragged it to the Assets and a new prefab created. Now I want to copy and use this prefab in other project/s too.

Screenshot of the prefab in the original project:

[image: Original project prefab]

Then in my new project after copying the prefab file only 7KB size:

[image: Prefab in new project]

Since it didn't work in the original project I did on the prefab right click and selected Export Package...

[image: Right click export package on the specific prefab]

If I'm not checking to Include dependencies it will create a package and after importing it in the other new project it will not work again.

But if I check and use the Include dependencies it will make a package of more then 32MB file size with almost everything in my original project not only the door prefab I wanted.

[image: Including dependencies]

Now it will work fine in the other project but it's crazy that I need to package almost the whole original project just for the door prefab.

In my new project I now so much things that are not connected to the door like scripts prefabs scenes.

And I did right click on the door only. I can't figure out why is it so hard to copy a simple small prefab and use it in another project.

Now in the new project I need to import the package and look in the screenshot the new package contains so much stuff look at the scroll bar on the right how many things it will import. 99.9% not connected in any way to the door prefab:

[image: Inporting]

This is the only way to use the door prefab in another project/s

Comment: select the prefab in your project assets, click export package, be sure its including dependancies, click export, now, you can import all the bits to make it work ..

Comment: @BugFinder That was supposed to be the solution but it's not. Selecting the prefab and making Export Package... will export the whole assets. You have to make first right click on the prefab then choose the option name: Select Dependencies then it will open in the assets only the Dependencies that are belong to the prefab and it will already select mark all the dependencies then you make right click on them and export package and it will make a package with all the dependencies of the selected prefab and it will work fine in other projects.

Comment: @BugFinder if you make first export package... it will put in the exporting window the whole Assets and then you will have like searching a niddle to select/unselect the assets and dependencies you want. I'm not sure why they did it this way. But making first choosing first the option Select Dependencies will export you a package of only the dependencies of the prefab.

Comment: Ive done it many times, if you right click the prefab, it only selects the dependancies of the prefab..

Comment: @BugFinder there is no way I need to export my whole Assets just for a simple small door prefab. And I did include dependencies it's including the whole Assets. That's not logic.

Comment: @DubiDuboni well, it maybe you're pre 2018, but the ones Ive done, it only selects the assets that are dependant for that prefab, not ALL prefabs/assets

Comment: @BugFinder I understand but the fact is look at my question at my screenshots. The fact is that when I did Export Package... on the specific selected prefab it exported the whole assets. And then look at my last screenshot the importing window. Is that logic that I will need to import my whole assets from the first project to the second project to make the prefab to work ?

Comment: @BugFinder I tried it over and over. Look at my screenshots. There is no way I need to export for example a script name EyeBlinking.cs to use the door prefab in other project. There is no link between the two in any way. Maybe I'm wrong but it's strange

Comment: There probably is something, somewhere.. it just may not be obvious without following all the asset code you've imported.

Comment: @BugFinder You right I guess. I checked it now again and it's missing two scripts. So I guess this scripts somewhere also need other scripts in other places and so on. I'm still thinking that there might be a way to track the prefab when creating it and store somehow somewhere only the dependencies that the prefab will need. In my case to use this simple little door prefab I needed almost to export the whole project to use it in another project. Seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: It seems to include scripts et all that reference that prefab, so, not only its descendants but things that maybe its parent.. Also, if you have a bunch of designs you imported depending on the import it might then cascade through all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 99.9% not connected in any way to the door prefab

It's wrong, they are relevant.

**Scripts**

The prefab has user scripts attached, then all the scripts will be included, because if you remove any class, the script may not be successfully compiled.

**Models, Materials, Textures, Shaders**

It looks like the prefab is created from a model, so all the model files, materials, textures and shaders will be included.

If a model file is a imported model (such as FBX), then the things (generated materials, animations, ...) related to this model will also be included.

**Sounds**

I see sounds are also in the list, so check your prefab, there may be a `AudioSource` with it.

---

So the conclusion is the simple small prefab is not simple in fact.

Comment: True but not accurate. I found that if you are making right click on specific prefab and choose Export Package... in the Exporting package window it will add the whole Assets items including all the scripts and packages and everything. and if you will uncheck the Include dependencies it will show only the prefab but then exporting the package will not work. But if before all that you will make on the prefab you want to export right click and choose first Select Dependencies it will show you in the Assets only the specific prefab Dependencies and already selected them and then you make

Comment: Right click and export package and it will export only this specific dependencies and it's working on the other project. For some reason Export Package... select the whole assets and not only the dependnecies of the prefab toy did right click on.

Comment: And you right I know the prefab need all it's scripts sounds components materials and textures but just Export Package... is not working. First make Select Dependencies then right click on them and export package. Why they did it this way I don't know.

Comment: You can to a simple test: 1 Create a cube _GameObject > 3D Object > Cube_. 2 Drag it to project window to make a prefab. 3 _Right click > Export Package_, only the prefab is selected in this moment.

Comment: Let me test it.

Comment: Id I just make a simple 3d cube and make prefab of it and export it a package it's working fine you right. But then I tried something else. I added a child to the cube first then added to the cube a material I have in the Assets somewhere then dragged the cube and created a prefab of it. Now when I did Export Package... when selecting the cube prefab it's showing me in the exporting window more then 100 items. Instead only the cube material and the child I added.

Comment: Try it your self. First make a simple 3d cube prefab it and select Export Package...then make a second test. Create another 3d cube add to it a child object and add to the cube also a material let's say in color red. Now drag this cube make prefab of it and select Export Package... And don't do it on empty new project. Do it on a project you have many assets and that the material is somewhere in other place in the Assets. Now tell me what happened.

Comment: Yes, and I find the different between `Select Dependency` and `Export Package` is `Select` method only select the immediate assets but `Export` seems select refered assets recursively. As I said in the answer `Select` may cause the scripts fail to compile, but `Export` ensures the package to work in another project.

Comment: Still the cube test, you can choose another mesh from an imported model for the cube, then `Select Dependency` method just select the lonly cube prefab. so there needs a dicision to export assets.

Comment: I agree with you. You right. I just wondering if there is a way to track the needed specific dependencies of the prefab when creating it and store or add this dependencies already somewhere instead exporting the whole assets (In my case to use the door prefab I need to export almost the whole project). Maybe there is no way I just wonder if it's possible. 99.9% of the stuff it's exporting are not connecting to the door prefab in any way.

Comment: Ok in the end I see that there is no a simple way to do it. And you right about it. Thanks.

Comment: I keep hearing about the "bug" where Unity attaches "all" the scripts, but how come no one is talking about the issue where it never exports any scripts even when "Dependencies" checked?